# Traefik V2 get wildcard certificate

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress

I have basic setup running after following this [tutorial](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/user-guides/crd-acme/)

But struggling to get wildcard certificate for domain from Let's Encrypt.

traefik configuration :

```
traefik.toml: |
  ## static configuration
  [global]
    checkNewVersion = true

  [entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.web]
      address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.websecure]
      address = ":443"

  [providers]
    [providers.kubernetesCRD]
    [providers.file]
      directory = "/etc/traefik/providers/"
      watch = true

  [log]
    level = "INFO"

  [accessLog]

  [api]
    insecure = true
    dashboard = true
    debug = true

  [metrics]
    [metrics.prometheus]
      buckets = [0.1,0.3,1.2,5.0]
      addEntryPointsLabels = true
      addServicesLabels = true
      entryPoint = "web"

  [ping]
    entryPoint = "web"

  [certificatesResolvers]
    [certificatesResolvers.default]
      [certificatesResolvers.default.acme]
        email = "admin@domain.com"
        caServer = "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
        storage = "acme.json"
        [certificatesResolvers.default.acme.dnsChallenge]
          provider = "route53"
          delayBeforeCheck = 0
          resolvers = ["1.1.1.1:53", "8.8.8.8:53"]

dynamic.toml: |
  ## dynamic configuration
  (Empty)
```

and route config :

```
---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-admin
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`traefik.domain.ca`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: traefik
      port: 8080

---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: whoami-notls
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: Host(`traefik.domain.ca`) && PathPrefix(`/notls`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 80

---

apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: whoami-tls
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`traefik.domain.ca`) && PathPrefix(`/tls`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: whoami
      port: 80
  tls:
    certResolver: default
```

I am able to get certificate for `traefik.domain.ca` but need to get wildcard certificate for entire domain (`*.domain.ca`). I am not able find any direct reference config for this.

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the `tls` block worked.

```
tls:
  certResolver: default
  domains:
    - main: dev.domain.ca
      sans:
        - "dev.domain.ca"
        - "*.dev.domain.ca"
```

Comment: This answer works. But. If you have multiple routers with this configuration, it will not work. So in one of your routers, set this configuration. In your other routers, just use `tls: {}`

Comment: @JasperKuperus can you please give me some example about it?

Comment: Imagine you have multiple `IngressRoute` documents and want TLS in all of them. If you copy/paste the block in this answer to all of those `IngressRoute`s, it will not work. What worked for me is add the block of code in this answer to one of the `IngressRoute`s and to all other `IngressRoute`s where I want TLS add `tls: {}`.